# YEAR() in SQL How to properly use year()

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE column_name BETWEEN YEAR("2020-01-01") and YEAR("2020-12-31");
```

Wanted to update a column where it is the year 2020. It somehow gives me this error

[image: the error message]

This is the table if you need references.

[image: the table]

Comment: `YEAR("2020-01-01")` would not return that error, it would give an error along the lines of "unknown column '2020-01-01'."

Comment: The column names in the query do not match those of the table, which makes your question rather unclear.

Comment: @Larnu - Presumably  `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is off. So this is treated as a string literal not an identifer

Comment: Or the column is a string and it's converting, say, 2020-02-30 to 1988

Comment: One would hope not though, @MartinSmith . Having `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` set to `OFF` is rarely a *good* idea.

Comment: Oddly enough, a picture containing columns that don't match your obfuscated code isn't particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE YEAR(Transaction_date) IN 2020
```

following @Serkan Eksioglu's answer, this method is also viable.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use YEAR at all, just specify a date range as constants:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE date_column >= '2020-01-01' AND date_column < '2021-01-01'
```

We use this form rather than `BETWEEN` because date columns can have times on and it's easier to just say "less than 2021-01-01" than "less than or equal to 2020-12-31 23:59:59.9999999999" to try and catch everything right down to the millisecond; BETWEEN is inclusive at both ends, whereas the `foo >= x AND foo < y` pattern is exclusive on the `y`

If your query is based on the TransactionDate pictured, then it seems to be timeless so `transactionDate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'` would work OK in that specific case; using lessthan is (in my opinion) a better pattern to get into in general because it applies in more cases

Answer (score 2):

what you cant compare is
YEAR("2020-01-01") is constant and equal to 2020 which is integer
and your column which is a date
i believe you just need to set a filter to get rows within 2020 so you should use something like

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE year(date_column_name)=2020;
```

or if you need a range

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE year(date_column_name) between 2010 and 2020;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it